# solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2}+\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x^2-x}$

Tags: calculus

I tried solve this limit.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2}+\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x^2-x}$

I tried multiply by $\sqrt{x^4+x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+5x}$, and apply L'Hospital. but this led to alot of work.. and this question seems to had a very easy and fast way to do. I know the answer is 3.

thanks any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Compute separately
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^4+x^2}-x^2$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x$$

Answer (score 1):

Continue with ajotatxe's hint:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^4 + x^2} - x^2$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 (\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} - 1)$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2 (\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} - 1)(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1)}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} $$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2  \frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} $$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2}+\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x^2-x}
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\left(x^2+\dfrac12\right)^2-\dfrac14} \\
&+\sqrt{\left(x+\frac52\right)^2-\frac{25}{4}} -x^2-x \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}{\left(x^2+\dfrac12\right)+\left|x+\frac52\right|-x^2-x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to+\infty}{\dfrac12+x+\frac52-x} \\
&= \color{blue}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: This is as wrong as can be, since this suggests, for example, that $$\sqrt{x^4+x^2}-x^2\to0$$ which is obviously not the case. @upvoter Why the upvote?